# Lower body fat problem

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat

I'm a 22 year old male-175cm height. I was 103kg, but, now I'm 75kg
for the past year. I have lost about 27kilos by a diet and exercise program. The exercise was focused on my lower body (like 100 squatting/day 5 days a week) because I felt I had much fat on my butt and thighs. The problem is, I still feel disproportion between my upper and lower body fat. My lower part is bigger, wider, and more fatty. I feel muscles on lower body but still fat. My stomach and chest are not fatty so that my shirt is smaller in size than my pants should be.  My narrowest waist circumference size is 78cm and widest hip circumference is 100 !!!!

I don't know any more if I lose more fat where would it be from upper or lower body.

And, also, I used many different types of body fat% calculators on the Internet. They all had the same percent 12.7%.  I totally don't trust that.

Any idea how I should decrease my lower body fat and size?

Comment: Are you doing any upper body exercises?  Could it be that you need more muscle in the upper body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aizul is right about targeting fat loss. Your body will burn fat in the areas it essentially chooses, ie where fat resources are easily available and ready to go. It might not be to your choosing, but for your body's furnace fat burning mechanism, it will get energy from fat based on it's most readily available source. Continue your program and your body will continue burning fat. Once it needs a new fat store to access, it will go there instead for an energy source.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot spot reduce fat**. Meaning no matter how much you train your legs, you will not burn off the fats in that region. Stick to **eating less**(caloric deficit), and continue training.

Comment: i eat under 1000calorie and with my exercises i need 2500+ calories ..the point is is it possible if i hit 70kg with 175cm height and still have the problem or would it be gone by that? ......

Comment: I can't tell you how long it takes to lose the fats or would there be no fats left once you reached 70 kg. However, I can tell you that once you see **visible changes to your body**, by taking pictures, using the mirror or even a weighing scale, then you would know if your problem is resolved.

Comment: @AhmedTarekKhalifa - You eat more than 1000 calories.5'9 and 165 lbs, 1000 calories is less than your BMR.

Answer (score 0):

Your body fat distribution is largely determined by your genes. Also adipose tissue can increase with excessive compression( for example sitting too much).
Once the cells are there, there is nothing you can do to get rid of them other than liposuction. The only thing you can do is to decrease their size by "starving" them. When you burn more calories than you eat, your body will start using the fat reserves and the cells wil shrink, NOT go away.

Also,you cannot 'spot reduce' fat. You will lose fat all over your body, not one place in peticular. When you exercise your lower body, your muscles will probably grow as well. This might contribute to more bulk in the legs, even though you are losing fat mass. Your hip bones might be wide as well contributiong to the effect.

My advice to you is to keep working out and eat a balanced diet (with a slight calorific deficit if you want to lose fat mass) and don't care too much about your appearance. Your health is far more important.